# Imitar un background en canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estoy tratando de imitar el background esta página https://gleec.com/instant-messages no me refiero a las particulas si no el degradado morado que tiene pero no puede hacerlo lo mas parecido al de ellos.

¿Alguna sugerencia para tratar de imitar ese tipo de degradado?

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: intente imitarlo con createRadialGradient pero no logre hacer el mismo difuminado

Comment: No puedes usar css? Si puedes, es sencillo hacerlo

Comment: mmm ps quería tratar de hacerlo en canvas pero bueno no es mala idea con css ahora como lo harías? usar linear gradient me daria un degradado en una sola dirección y el radial ps seria muy radial xd la idea es que se logre un difuminado lo mas parecido al de la pagina

Comment: Muéstranos lo que estás consiguiendo usando los snippets que te proporciona el editor. (Para eso tienes que editar tu pregunta)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es trivial hacerlo. Lo que ves en el background es una textura hecha con [Three.js](https://threejs.org/) usando el [renderer webgl](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer).

Adicionalmente, el script que carga el sitio toma un elemento con id `#app` y en él monta un componente de [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)

Al montar el componente, llena todo el HTML que va dentro del `body`, ese HTML tiene elementos con ciertas clases, y seguramente en el evento `mount` del componente se hacen llamados a Three.js para asignarle las distintas texturas, comportamientos y cámaras a los respectivos canvas.

El script que se está llamando está minificado y consolidado aparentemente usando webpack (y vuejs-template-loader) en donde se encuentra el componente mismo más three.js y otras dependencias. Esto quiere decir que es virtualmente imposible saber qué evento llena qué elemento con qué textura.

Adicionalmente las texturas se asocian a materiales y etc etc. Three.js no es trivial para nada.

**Respuesta resumida:**

Tienes que usar Three.js y renderear con WebGL. Pese a que el resultado de esta operación efectivamente se usa para llenar un canvas, no podrías lograr más que una imitación muy lejana con funciones nativas de un Canvas.

**Ejemplo funcional**

Te dejo un ejemplo usando lo menos complejo que pude:

- Creo una escena
- Creo una cámara
- Defino la altura de la cámara
- Creo un renderer WebGL y le doy propiedades
- Ese renderer me crea un canvas y yo lo añado al document.body
- Creo una geometría planar, un material mesh y añado esto a la escena
- Creo tres luces, de distintos colores, como focos apuntando a cierta distancia sobre cierta posición
- Agrego las luces a la escena
- Le digo al renderer que dibuje todo lo que declaré

```js
function init() {
      var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 30);
        camera.position.z = 25;

        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });

                renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
        var meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

        scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, meshMaterial));

        var lights = [];
        lights[0] = new THREE.PointLight(0xff0000, 1, 100, 2);
        lights[1] = new THREE.PointLight(0x00ff00, 1, 100, 2);
        lights[2] = new THREE.PointLight(0x0000ff, 1, 100, 2);

        lights[0].position.set(-25, -2, 20);
        lights[1].position.set(25, 5, 20);
        lights[2].position.set(0, 0, 15);

        scene.add(lights[0]);
        scene.add(lights[1]);
        scene.add(lights[2]);

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    window.setTimeout(init,300);
```

```css
canvas {
        width: 90%;
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ahora si entendí, ya estaba pensando que imitarlo no seria fácil tu explicación me ayudo a entender gracias :D

Comment: Te dejé un ejemplo funcionando que puedes copiar y pegar en tu sitio, sólo tendrías que jugar con las tres luces que le puse (color, posición, atenuación)

Comment: woo muchas gracias me ayudaste mucho voy a probar enserio muchas gracias